# How to print the whole range of data from Excel in python using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have written below code that prints the only first row of the excel from range A1 to D1. How I can print the whole range from A1 to D3?

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('Sample.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
Data = sht1.range(f"A{1}:D{3}").value
idx = 0
value = Data[idx]
print(value[0],value[1] ,value[2], value[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

use [used_range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.used_range):

```
import xlwings as xw

filepath = r"a_file.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(filepath)
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

print(sheet.used_range)
```

Comment: i need to print out  the data in that range

Comment: `for a_cell in sheet.used_range:  print(a_cell.value)`